Getting undefined for file upload in node js using multer
I am not able to upload the any file or image using multer node package in mac. But same code working fine in windows. I'm using postman for api call. when I hit the api and inside console log Im getting undefined for req.file
const express = require('express');
        const app = express();
        const multer  = require('multer');
        const storage = multer.diskStorage({
           destination: function (req, file, cb) {
             cb(null, 'uploads')
           },
           filename: function (req, file, cb) {
              console.log(file)
           //   const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9)
             cb(null, file.originalname)
           }
         })
        const upload = multer({storage: storage})
        
        app.post('/post', upload.single('avatar'), (req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.file)
           if (!req.file) {
              return res.status(400).send([{ msg: "File is missing",err }])
            }
        else{
           return res.status(200).send([{ msg: "working", }])
        }
        });
        app.listen(3000,(err,succes)=>{
         if (err) {
            console.log(err)
         }else{
            console.log("Server is running in port number",3000)
         }
        });


Please have a look at [ask]. "It doesn't work" is not a question. What exactly is not working? Are you receiving any errors? If so then please add the errors (as text) inside the question

Have you actually created the uploads directory? Using the callback for destination requires that you create it manually. Also, follow the error handling guide for debugging hints

Yeah i have created the folder in same path where Index.js is exists.

Can you please write a small Nodejs client and test it. This is to rule out if something specific to postman.
The code below is a sample Nodejs client.
client.js //run it as node client
const fs = require('fs');
const axios = require('axios');
const FormData = require('form-data');

const formdata = new FormData();

// adding the file
formdata.append('avatar', fs.createReadStream('./avatar.jpg'));

axios
  .post('http://localhost:3000/post', formdata)
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });


Postman is the problem. By using this method i found out the api is working fine. thank you

Thank you for your confirmation. It not only brings a formal closure to the question and but also will encourage other info seekers to make use of this content.
